# how to insert date into database using jsp?

Tags: sql, oracle, jsp

I'm trying to insert date into the database with a query that I do in java, but I get this error

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation

```
String req=request.getParameter("date");

try
{
      SimpleDateFormat d=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
      Date dt=d.parse(req);          

      java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(dt.getTime());    

      Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
      Connection co=null;
      co=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","java","java");
      String sql="insert Into login_table(date_dt)values(?)";        

      PreparedStatement st=co.prepareStatement(sql);
      st.setDate(1, sqlDate);
      ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
}
catch(Exception xe)
{
     out.println(xe);
}
```

but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You probably need [`executeUpdate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeUpdate%28%29) instead of [`executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#executeQuery%28%29) -- But I doubt this could be related. What is the exact type of your column `date_dt` ? Which version of Oracle do you use ?

Comment: data type is date and version oracle 10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it was that!

```
  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery(sql);
  //                           ^^^
```

No! Use:

```
  ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery();
```

Or better

```
  st.executeUpdate();
```

---

When you call `executeQuery(sql)`, you in fact call the inherited [`Statement.executeQuery`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery%28java.lang.String%29) that won't use your prepared statement at all.

Answer (score 1):

also you can write.

```
int returnval=st.executeUpdate();
```

Returns:
either 
(1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or 
(2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing